# Stuck in MongoDB commands

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

This is ***really important*** to me.
In the following, I should manipulate data using
MongoDB Aggregate pipeline & $Lookup. I am NOT allowed to use MongoCampass for
this section.
There is a Mongo database called Accessories with the following collections:

1. **Products** – all columns
2. **ProductStock** – product_id, product_name, warehouse_id,warehouse_name, location_id,    address, country_name,
   region_name,quantity
3. **ProductSold** – product_id, total qty sold

***products(product details):***

```
[
{"Product_ID":1,"Product_Name":"G.Skill Ripjaws V Series","Description":"Speed:DDR4-3000,Type:288-pin DIMM,CAS:15Module:8x8GBSize:64GB","Standard_Cost":450,"List_Price":640,"Category_ID":5},
{"Product_ID":2,"Product_Name":"Intel Xeon E5-2697 V4","Description":"Speed:2.3GHz,Cores:18,TDP:145W","Standard_Cost":2144,"List_Price":2554,"Category_ID":1},
{"Product_ID":3,"Product_Name":"Corsair CB-9060011-WW","Description":"Chipset:GeForce GTX 1080 Ti,Memory:11GBCore Clock:1.57GHz","Standard_Cost":573,"List_Price":799,"Category_ID":2},
{"Product_ID":4,"Product_Name":"AMD 100-505989","Description":"Chipset:FirePro W9100,Memory:32GBCore Clock:930MHz","Standard_Cost":2128,"List_Price":2699,"Category_ID":2},
{"Product_ID":5,"Product_Name":"PNY VCQK6000-PB","Description":"Chipset:Quadro K6000,Memory:12GBCore Clock:902MHz","Standard_Cost":1740,"List_Price":2290,"Category_ID":2},
{"Product_ID":6,"Product_Name":"Zotac ZT-P10810A-10P","Description":"Chipset:GeForce GTX 1080 Ti,Memory:11GBCore Clock:1.48GHz","Standard_Cost":702,"List_Price":849,"Category_ID":2},
{"Product_ID":7,"Product_Name":"G.Skill Ripjaws V Series","Description":"Speed:DDR4-3200,Type:288-pin DIMM,CAS:15Module:8x8GBSize:64GB","Standard_Cost":602,"List_Price":680,"Category_ID":5},
{"Product_ID":8,"Product_Name":"Intel Xeon E5-1650 V4","Description":"Speed:3.6GHz,Cores:6,TDP:140W","Standard_Cost":535,"List_Price":601,"Category_ID":1},
{"Product_ID":9,"Product_Name":"Intel Xeon E5-2640 V4","Description":"Speed:2.4GHz,Cores:10,TDP:90W","Standard_Cost":738,"List_Price":899,"Category_ID":1},
{"Product_ID":10,"Product_Name":"Crucial","Description":"Speed:DDR4-2133,Type:288-pin DIMM,CAS:15Module:2x16GBSize:32GB","Standard_Cost":580,"List_Price":811,"Category_ID":5},
{"Product_ID":11,"Product_Name":"PNY VCQP5000-PB","Description":"Chipset:Quadro P5000,Memory:16GBCore Clock:1.61GHz","Standard_Cost":1602,"List_Price":2015,"Category_ID":2},
{"Product_ID":12,"Product_Name":"Gigabyte GV-N108TAORUSX W-11GD","Description":"Chipset:GeForce GTX 1080 Ti,Memory:11GBCore Clock:1.63GHz","Standard_Cost":596,"List_Price":824,"Category_ID":2},
{"Product_ID":13,"Product_Name":"G.Skill Ripjaws V Series","Description":"Speed:DDR4-3333,Type:288-pin DIMM,CAS:16Module:4x16GBSize:64GB","Standard_Cost":618,"List_Price":704,"Category_ID":5},
{"Product_ID":14,"Product_Name":"G.Skill Ripjaws V Series","Description":"Speed:DDR4-3333,Type:288-pin DIMM,CAS:16Module:4x16GBSize:64GB","Standard_Cost":633,"List_Price":704,"Category_ID":5},
{"Product_ID":15,"Product_Name":"G.Skill Trident Z","Description":"Speed:DDR4-3466,Type:288-pin DIMM,CAS:16Module:4x16GBSize:64GB","Standard_Cost":601,"List_Price":725,"Category_ID":5},
{"Product_ID":16,"Product_Name":"Intel Core i7-6900K","Description":"Speed:3.2GHz,Cores:8,TDP:140W","Standard_Cost":792,"List_Price":889,"Category_ID":1},
{"Product_ID":17,"Product_Name":"Corsair Vengeance LPX","Description":"Speed:DDR4-3333,Type:288-pin DIMM,CAS:15Module:4x16GBSize:64GB","Standard_Cost":595,"List_Price":699,"Category_ID":5},
```

***productSold(product sold):***

```
[
{"Product_ID":1,"TotalQuantity":457},
{"Product_ID":2,"TotalQuantity":229},
{"Product_ID":3,"TotalQuantity":147},
{"Product_ID":4,"TotalQuantity":441},
{"Product_ID":5,"TotalQuantity":109},
{"Product_ID":6,"TotalQuantity":245},
```

***productStock(stock in inventory):***

```
[{"Product_ID":3,"Product_Name":"Corsair CB-9060011-WW","Warehouse_ID":1,"Warehouse_Name":"Southlake, Texas","Location_ID":5,"Address":"2014 Jabberwocky Rd","Country_name":"United States of America","region_name":"Americas","Total_Quantity":106},
{"Product_ID":4,"Product_Name":"AMD 100-505989","Warehouse_ID":1,"Warehouse_Name":"Southlake, Texas","Location_ID":5,"Address":"2014 Jabberwocky Rd","Country_name":"United States of America","region_name":"Americas","Total_Quantity":106},
{"Product_ID":5,"Product_Name":"PNY VCQK6000-PB","Warehouse_ID":1,"Warehouse_Name":"Southlake, Texas","Location_ID":5,"Address":"2014 Jabberwocky Rd","Country_name":"United States of America","region_name":"Americas","Total_Quantity":106},
{"Product_ID":6,"Product_Name":"Zotac ZT-P10810A-10P","Warehouse_ID":1,"Warehouse_Name":"Southlake, Texas","Location_ID":5,"Address":"2014 Jabberwocky Rd","Country_name":"United States of America","region_name":"Americas","Total_Quantity":107},
{"Product_ID":11,"Product_Name":"PNY VCQP5000-PB","Warehouse_ID":1,"Warehouse_Name":"Southlake, Texas","Location_ID":5,"Address":"2014 Jabberwocky Rd","Country_name":"United States of America","region_name":"Americas","Total_Quantity":108},
{"Product_ID":12,"Product_Name":"Gigabyte GV-N108TAORUSX W-11GD","Warehouse_ID":1,"Warehouse_Name":"Southlake, Texas","Location_ID":5,"Address":"2014 Jabberwocky Rd","Country_name":"United States of America","region_name":"Americas","Total_Quantity":108},
{"Product_ID":80,"Product_Name":"Intel Xeon E5-1650 V3","Warehouse_ID":1,"Warehouse_Name":"Southlake, Texas","Location_ID":5,"Address":"2014 Jabberwocky Rd","Country_name":"United States of America","region_name":"Americas","Total_Quantity":125},}
```

Queries:
Use MongoDB commands to demonstrate the following:

1.  Query 1 – Implement a query to find out those products which have
   never been sold before
2.  **Query 2** – For those products from Query 1, implement a query to find
   their total stock available arranged in descending order. What
   insight do you discover from the results of the query?
3.  **Query 3** – Implement a query to find the unduplicated sets of
   country_name and warehouse_names in combination
4.  **Query 4** – Implement a query to find the number of different
   products held by each warehouse (state the name of warehouse)

First query that works:

```
  db.Products.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "ProductSold",
      localField: "Product_ID",
      foreignField: "Product_ID",
      as: "sold"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      sold: { $size: 0 }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      Product_ID: 1,
      Product_Name: 1,
      Description: 1,
      Standard_Cost: 1,
      List_Price: 1,
      Category_ID: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $count: "count"
  }
]);
```

Query 2 :

```
    db.Products.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "ProductSold",
      localField: "Product_ID",
      foreignField: "Product_ID",
      as: "sold"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      sold: { $size: 0 }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "ProductStock",
      localField: "Product_ID",
      foreignField: "Product_ID",
      as: "stockData"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$stockData",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$Product_ID",
      Product_Name: { $first: "$Product_Name" },
      Description: { $first: "$Description" },
      Standard_Cost: { $first: "$Standard_Cost" },
      List_Price: { $first: "$List_Price" },
      Category_ID: { $first: "$Category_ID" },
      Total_Stock: { $sum: "$stockData.quantity" }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      Total_Stock: -1 // Sort in descending order of Total_Stock
    }
  }
]);
```

There is suppose to be 32 output for both queries.

**but it is wrong, please help** I also need help and guidance for the rest of the queries please, Thank you.

Comment: Looks like there is a typo in the `foreignField` for that query to me. But I'm not sure this site is really designed for folks to write the other queries (homework?) for you from from scratch. You did good on the first one, give the others a try. Also "not allowed to use Compass" - because...? It's just a client tool. Things like Compass and mongoplayground are great for testing queries out

Comment: Here's a [mongoplayground.net configuration](https://mongoplayground.net/p/A7ypNfCIiCv) with your sample collections and query.  If you eliminate the `"$count"` stage, do you get the output you want for _Query 1_?

Comment: @rickhg12hs Yes, it works now but i am really lost for query2, my ,method dosen't seem to be working

Comment: If you are having difficulty with any specific query, it's best to ask a new question.

Comment: You write "...but it is wrong."  Wrong how?   Show a doc or two from the pipeline output.   Also, double check that your assumptions are correct about the data.  Just because a product never sold (Query 1), does not automatically mean that it *must* appear in the `ProductStock`.   Make sure your `$lookup` keys are working properly.

Answer (score 0):

watch out DAAA Module coordinator watching already

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).